# Java/Spring UnrecoverableKeyException with SSL

Tags: java, spring, ssl, keytool

**Please note**: although this specific question involves the [Ldaptive](http://www.ldaptive.org/) library, I strongly believe that it is purely a Java `keytool`/SSL/Spring question at heart.

I am using Ldaptive on my Java (Spring) app server for authenticating users against an LDAP/AD server. When I deploy the WAR to Tomcat and start it up, I get the following exception:

```
    (Large stack trace above this, below is the root exception)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: requested entry requires a password
    at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:459)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1290)
    at org.ldaptive.ssl.KeyStoreUtils.getEntry(KeyStoreUtils.java:129)
    at org.ldaptive.ssl.KeyStoreSSLContextInitializer.createTrustManagers(KeyStoreSSLContextInitializer.java:116)
    at org.ldaptive.ssl.AbstractSSLContextInitializer.getTrustManagers(AbstractSSLContextInitializer.java:41)
    at org.ldaptive.ssl.AbstractSSLContextInitializer.initSSLContext(AbstractSSLContextInitializer.java:84)
    at org.ldaptive.ssl.TLSSocketFactory.initialize(TLSSocketFactory.java:68)
    at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiProvider.getJndiStartTLSConnectionFactory(JndiProvider.java:162)
    ... 83 more
```

The error is coming from this Spring bean:

```
<bean id="sslConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ssl.SslConfig">
    <property name="credentialConfig">
        <bean class="org.ldaptive.ssl.KeyStoreCredentialConfig"
            p:keyStore="file:/etc/myapp/keys.jks"
            p:keyStorePassword="password"
            p:keyStoreType="JKS"
            p:keyStoreAliases="kw-dj93d3j9-29kd-dj9k-dkow-dk3jd93jsjs8" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

As you can see, I'm telling Ldaptive to look on my local file system, under `/etc/myapp`, to find a Java KeyStore called `keys.jks`. In this keystore is a key named "*kw-dj93d3j9-29kd-dj9k-dkow-dk3jd93jsjs8*".

When I use `keytool` to inspect this key:

```
cd /etc/myapp
keytool -list -keystore keys.jks
Enter keystore password:  password

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

kw-dj93d3j9-29kd-dj9k-dkow-dk3jd93jsjs8, May 1, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <Long hexidecimal strings here...>
```

It is worth mentioning that this is *not* a self-signed cert. This is a cert from a reputable CA.

So I know the key is located in the keystore. However, I seem to remember that when I added this key to the JKS (several months ago), **the key itself had a password on it** (that I also set as "password"). However I've tried mucking around with `keytool` to see if I can get it to ask me for the key's/alias's individual password (instead of the store-wide password) and I can't reproduce this, but just food for thought. If I had to guess, the `keyStorePassword` field in the Spring bean is correct, but the key itself requires a password, and Ldaptive isn't taking that into account...

In any event, any ideas as to why I'm seeing this exception? And if I am correct, and I can't change Ldaptive's source code, then what are my options? Are there any `keytool` commands I can use to drop the individual key's password, and to just accept the store-wide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace doesn't appear to match the configuration you posted. Specifically:

```
at org.ldaptive.ssl.KeyStoreSSLContextInitializer.createTrustManagers(KeyStoreSSLContextInitializer.java:116)
at org.ldaptive.ssl.AbstractSSLContextInitializer.getTrustManagers(AbstractSSLContextInitializer.java:41)
```

is configuring trust managers, not key managers. I would expect that exception to come from this config:

```
    <bean class="org.ldaptive.ssl.KeyStoreCredentialConfig"
        p:trustStore="file:/etc/myapp/keys.jks"
        p:trustStorePassword="password"
        p:trustStoreType="JKS"
        p:trustStoreAliases="kw-dj93d3j9-29kd-dj9k-dkow-dk3jd93jsjs8" />
```

Nevertheless, if you've found a bug please file an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/issues/list).

Comment: Must be a bug; I ended up exporting my SSL cert out of the keystore, and using an `X509CredentialConfig` instead, and then configured it like so: `p:trustCertificates="classpath:/WEB-INF/mycert.cer"`. Works like a champ.

Comment: That configuration is not equivalent to your original post. The CredentialConfig objects are used to configure both authentication and trust material. Your original post configured a keystore to use for authentication. Your solution uses an X509 certificate to configure trust. So if you import your certificate to a keystore and use a KeyStoreCredentialConfig with p:trustStore properties that will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you should be able to validate whether the key still has a password by exporting it to PKCS12 and inspecting with OpenSSL [instructions in thread [here]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore).  Of course that thread also points out a free GUI tool which appears to allow you to directly edit the JKS, which may be simpler if you're comfortable using it.

Worst case you can always generate a new self-signed to test with to verify that the problem is with the JKS and not something larger in the configuration / environment.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception says "requires password" not "cannot recover" I'm pretty sure Ldaptive is calling getEntry with no password rather than a wrong one. A privatekey entry always requires a password, so this is either Ldaptive code or config, and I'd expect the latter is more likely, FWLTW.

Assuming "added this key" means generated with `-genkeypair` (or older equivalent `-genkey`), that operation does prompt separately (after the subject-name dialog) for a per-key password that can be different from the store password, but by default (if you hit return) is the same. AFAICS the only keytool options that need and thus prompt for a key password on an existing entry are `-keypasswd` `-certreq` and `-importkeystore`, and the first of those is the way to change it. So run (any ordering of)

```
keytool -keystore $file -keypasswd -alias $name
```

and if it prompts you for "Enter key password" then the entry does have a per-key password different from the store password. If it immediately prompts for "New key password" then the key password *currently is* the store password; just control-C out. If there is a distinct key password and you can't remember or guess it you're out of luck; you'd need to break the encryption and while I haven't looked at what exactly JKS uses I'm confident it's pretty strong.

Not necessary for your question, but that's a very intriguing-looking alias name. If it has some significance that you don't need to keep secret, I wouldn't mind knowing.